# Random choosing 2 dictionaries: with same value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, random

From a dictionary I wanna choose 2 dictionaries randomly who have their value[0] == 'C'.

```
d = {"1": ('B', [3, 4, 8]), "2": ('C', [2, 6, 8]), "3": ('C', [9, 10, 11, 13]), "4": ("E", [14, 15, 16, 17]), "5": ("C", [20])}
for key, val in d.items():
        if val[0] == 'B':

            b = val[0] == 'C'
            res = key, val = random.choice(list(d.items()))
            print(res)

e = {"2": ('C', [2, 6, 8]), "3": ('C', [9, 10, 11, 13])}
e = {"2, 3": ('C', [2, 6, 8] , [9, 10, 11, 13])}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want the 2 tuples selected to be different from each other:

```
>>> dict(random.sample([(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v[0] == "C"], 2))
{'5': ('C', [20]), '3': ('C', [9, 10, 11, 13])}
```